Finding measure representation for rank 2 moment matrices

Assuming the following equation has a solution, I'm interested in finding any concrete values of $x_{1},\dots x_{n},y_{1},\dots y_{n},c_{1},c_{2},R$ that fulfills it.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
x_{1} & y_{1} \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
x_{1}^{n} & y_{1}^{n} \\
x_{1}^{2} & y_{1}^{2} \\
x_{1}x_{2} & y_{1}y_{2} \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
x^{d}_{n} & y^{d}_{n} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} &  \\
 &  c_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
R = S
$$
Where $S\in \mathbb{R}^{{n+d \choose d} \times 2}$ is given, $R$ is a 2 by 2 unitary matrix, $c_{1},c_{2}\geq 0$ and $c_{1}^{2}+c_{2}^{2} = 1$. All variables here are assumed to be real.

The matrix on the left is composed of two columns of monomial basis. Suppose a solution exists (it can guaranteed by flat extension for instance), then $SS^{\top}$ is a moment matrix. Since I'm only interested in finding one solution, when $n=1$, $i$.$e$. the univariate case, this can be solved by Prony's method where we guess the coefficients of some polynomial with $x_{1}$ and $y_{1}$ as root. However, I'm not too sure about the multivariate case. I'm mostly concerned with $n$ being small, and $d$ being large, but other cases might also be interesting.
There are papers on mutivariate prony's method, which I haven't got a chance to read carefully, but I felt the problem is way simpler when we only have two "points" to consider, as $c_{2}$ depends on $c_{1}$ and $R$ is also simple. It might just require some basic linear algebra. Alternatively, if numerical methods can solve this, it would also be great. In either case, I'm looking for something that's computationally feasible.
